# Create Cart Item Record

Tags: apex, b2b

I have a trouble inserting Cart Item record in B2B Org, whenever Im trying to run this code, it throws me Internal Salesforce.com Error.

System.Debug shows the same error.

```
CartItem ci = new CartItem();
ci.CartId = cartId;
ci.Name ='My New Item';
ci.Product2Id = prod2Id;
ci.CurrencyIsoCode = 'EUR';
ci.ListPrice = 12;
ci.Quantity = 1;
ci.SalesPrice = 12;
ci.AdjustmentAmount = 0;
ci.TotalLineAmount = 24;
insert ci;
```

Comment: Give more details (exact text of the error, when does it happen) please and broader context (the whole apex class, from where does the process starts). Try debugging just before the insert.

Comment: The exact error message is: Internal Salesforce.com Error. I launched that code thru Anonymous Window, debug still shows Internal Salesforce.com Error

Comment: Does the product has the correct entitlement? Is the user properly configured? One alternative to this would be to leverage ConnectApi's CommerceCart functionalities: In our project, we relied on connectapi for our cart transactions https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_output_cart_item.htm

Comment: Use `ci.Type = 'Product'`. It will work.